# How can I create a RateLimiter for 10 requests per 10 seconds using Rust Governor?

Tags: rust

Is there a way in Rust with Governor, to create a RateLimiter for 10/10s?

You can create the Quota:

```
    let q10 = Quota::with_period(Duration::from_secs(10))
        .unwrap()
        .allow_burst(NonZeroU32::new(10).unwrap());
```

However this only replenishes one every 10seconds.

And there doesn't seem to be a way to completely replenish a quota every some seconds correct?
The only way seems to be replacing the RateLimiter completely each 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe `governor` can do what you want. [The ratelimit crate](https://docs.rs/ratelimit/latest/ratelimit/) seems to, though.

```
let ratelimiter = Ratelimiter::builder(10, Duration::from_secs(10))
    .max_tokens(10)
    .build()
    .unwrap();
```

This snippet will create a limiter that allows 10 requests every 10 seconds, with a max burst of 10. This means that you can make 10 requests in quick succession but must wait 10 seconds before sending any more.

Comment: That is a nice crate :)
The issue is that there is no .wait() (only [.try_wait()](https://docs.rs/ratelimit/latest/ratelimit/struct.Ratelimiter.html) ), and I need to await two limiters at the same time :(

Comment: This should still work! `try_wait` is not blocking, so you can call it twice, and use both results immediately. You would just have to wait for the shorter duration of the two, before checking again, and only proceeding once both calls return `Ok`.

Comment: But then in a congestion scenario (1000 requests send in 1 second, with limits 2/2s + 10/10s), await is neccesary. As making the middleware await x seconds, will go over the limit.

Comment: I don't follow. The 2/2 limit would be hit first, which will cause a backoff. Then, after some time, the 10/10 is reached, and will be backed off. Once both clear, you can then allow more requests through.

Comment: But it cannot wait until the first next one is available. As that would make it possible for 20 requests to have waited for x time and .try_wait again. Where some will fail again.
It would then need some recursion for it to work.
And it should take either of the limits, whichever fills up first.

Comment: Perhaps you have missed a crucial point, `try_wait` does not block, it will return immediately. So you can collect the results of both limiters at the same time, multiple times. You can use this behaviour to implement the solution you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished like this:

```
let lim = RateLimiter::direct(Quota::per_second(nonzero!(1u32)).allow_burst(nonzero!(10u32)));
```

It is slightly different, you're replenishing at one per second and there is a burst limit of 10, but in the long run the rate of requests is the same.